# Links won't open in Dolphin using U1 Client on KDE

Tags: ubuntu-one, kubuntu

No matter if I click on a link in the UI (for example, the 'Official Support' button) or the 'Show me my Ubuntu One folder' button the UI won't open the link/folder using Dolphin (tested on Kubuntu Oneiric).

Comment: The support links should work; does `xdg-open http://u1.to/` work?

Answer (score 1):

I have filed [bug #931807 on Launchpad](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntuone-control-panel/+bug/931807) to track this problem.

Answer (score 0):

KDE is not supported by the Ubuntu One client. As far as I know, Nautilus (the GNOME file manager) is the only program that'll work with the U1 client. It can be installed on Kubuntu without issue.

Comment: The links in the control panel (which the OP is referring to) *should* work, however; xdg-open must be busted, somehow?